# How to Display only couple of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 2 keys and 1 value. I only want to print the keys and first 3 values in dictionary. Dictionary example:

```
newdict={('Brain Danielson', 'Canada'): 7887, 
('Kofi Kingston', 'Gana'): 7718, 
('Drew McIntryre', 'England'): 8105,
('John Cena','USA'):9078
}
```

Output should be:

```
First: Bryan Danielson, Canada
Second: Kofi Kingston, Gana
Third: Drew McIntryre, England
```

Comment: Just to adjust the vocabulary here, what you have is a dictionary with composite keys (tuples) and numeric values. You want to print the first 3 **keys** with a corresponding prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without zip.

You can convert the dict into a list temporarily and read off the data you need or pipe it to where you would like using a small for loop.:

```
newdict = {
    ('Brain Danielson', 'Canada'): 7887,
    ('Kofi Kingston', 'Gana'): 7718,
    ('Drew McIntryre', 'England'): 8105,
    ('John Cena', 'USA'): 9078
}
data = list(newdict.keys())

for d in (data)[0:3]:
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a simple loop with zip() by combining your 3 prompts with the dictionary's keys

```
for nth,key in zip(('First:','Second:','Third:'),newdict):
    print(nth,*key)
```

output:

```
First: Brain Danielson Canada
Second: Kofi Kingston Gana
Third: Drew McIntryre England
```

*zip() will only iterate through the shortest source (in this case your list of prompts) so the 4th and subsequent dictionary keys will not be processed.*

If you need the keys assigned to variables, you could use an iterator on the dictionary and get each key using the next() function:

```
first,second,third = map(next,[iter(newdict)]*3)
print("First:",*first)
print("Second:",*second)
print("Third:",*third)
```

There is also a simpler notation (but it is inefficient as it will go through the whole dictionary just to get the first 3 keys):

```
first,second,third,*_ = newdict
```

Answer (score 0):

for nth,key in zip(('First:','Second:','Third:'),newdict):
print(nth,*key)

Comment: Why repeat an answer posted 20 minutes earlier ?